How can I get EIP-1193 compatible signer in a server-side environmnet?
When I try to use Safe.init() in server-side, since I'm integrated it with frame.js, I want to let ppl can sign the safe tx via frame, but I cannot access window.ethereum. Any suggestion?
export const POST = frames(async (ctx) => {
const { senderAddress, safeAddress, to, value, data } = ctx.searchParams;
    
if (!senderAddress || !safeAddress || !to || !value || !data) { throw new Error("Missing required parameters"); }
    
try { const protocolKit = await Safe.init({ provider: window?.ethereum, signer: senderAddress, safeAddress: safeAddress, })


Thank you a lot for your questions.
As you rightfully said, you cannot access window on the server side, so signing a message with MetaMask is not possible on the server.
If you want to use window.ethereum, you must ensure that your code runs on the client side only.
This issue is not related to Safe but to the JS framework you use. As you use React, you could have a look into Safe React Hooks.
If this answers your question, please mark it as answered. If you have further questions regarding Safe{Core} SDK, I am happy to assist.
